# CursorLoader selection

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, android-cursorloader

I have managed to view a list of contacts in my android app, the list is unsorted so I would like to sort it from A to Z.

My CursorLoader look as follows:

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
};

private static final String SELECTION =null;
private String[] mSelectionArgs ={ };

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {

    return new CursorLoader {
            getApplicationContext(),
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            mSelectionArgs,
            null
    }
}
```

Please advise parameters that the above selection variables must take to for example sort the contacts alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last constructor parameter to "data ASC":

```
new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        PROJECTION,
        SELECTION,
        mSelectionArgs,
        "data ASC");
```

Where **data** is the column that should be alphabetically sorted.

Comment: nope did not work issued error. no such column: data (code 1) while compiling. When I remove the "data ASC" and put null back it runs fine.

Comment: @the_big_blackbox  what the name of the column that you want to alphabetically sort?

Comment: hi alexios it is the display_name column, I have updated the above for the projection variable.

Comment: @the_big_blackbox could you please try my updated answer? Is that working?

Comment: hi alexios sorry the late reply I was busy with other parts of the app. thanks so much it did work